# Please help me do data recovery from a phone stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, huawei

I bought a Huawei Honor 5C Pro phone 2 years back and so far it had been working well. Two nights back, the phone shut down because of empty battery and I slept without putting it on charge.

The next morning, I started to charge it but the red light started blinking continuously for some time. Then, the honor logo was repeatedly flashing on and off without it reaching the lock screen.After every two or three times of flashing honor logo, it flashes emui with reboot,factory reset and clear partition cache options but it doesn't stop for me to choose any option.

This bootloop happens continuously while it is charging and if I remove it from charging, it still bootloops and doesn't shutdown no matter what. It bootloops until all battery is drained and then shuts down.

Only one time did it open while charge was 10% but after that, it shut down and hasn't stopped bootlooping.

Unfortunately, the battery is not removable.

Also, the problem is, when I put it on charge, for some time a red light blinks and then without any input from user, the phone switches on, boots to Honor logo and after every 2-3 honor logo flashes, it flashes to emui (with reboot, factory reset and clear partition cache option) but the screen immediately blacks out before I can choose any option.

The morning it happened, after many tries, it did open once at 10% charge. But it again switched off and hasn't stopped bootlooping since.

I don't care if the phone doesn't work. I just need the data stored on the ROM. If the phone can work, that's great but the data is more important.

As long as the phone keeps charging, this boot loop keeps happening despite me trying to switch off the phone. When I remove it from charging, it still boot loops until battery is low.

**Please help me get back control of the phone or atleast recover the data stored on the phone's ROM.**

Comment: This is your the second post on the same topic. Please to only ask one question per topic. You can edit your old question at any time and add or change something.

Answer (score -1):

When your Android's system files stop communicating correctly, the device may end up having difficulty starting. Boot loops are the result of system files not knowing how to function during the initial start-up phase and can be caused by a variety of things, from downloading new apps to accidentally changing system files.

**Soft Reset the Android Phone**

The first step in dealing with a boot loop is performing a simple soft reset. Turn off your Android phone and remove the battery. If you're unable to remove the battery on your specific model of phone, leave the device powered off for at least five minutes. Turn the device back on to see if the boot issue has been resolved. Sometimes a quick soft reset is all it takes to shake bugs out of the startup process.

**Factory Reset the Device**

Factory resetting your phone will completely wipe it of data and restore it to the original factory settings. Power down the device and boot it into Recovery Mode. The exact steps for booting into Recovery Mode depend on the phone's manufacturer – consult your user manual. From there, select “Wipe Data/Factory Reset” and start the process. After the wipe, select “Reboot System Now” from the main menu.

**Using CWM Recovery**

If your phone is rooted already with CWM, the steps for wiping the device are different. Power down the phone and launch it into CWM Recovery Mode by pressing the Home, power, and volume up keys at the same time (this key combination may be different for your specific Android phone). Select “Advanced,” choose “Wipe,” and then pick “Dalvik cache.” Next, choose “Mounts and Storage” and then use “Wipe /cache.” Reboot the phone and the issue should be resolved.You can do same things if you have TWRP recovery.

**Use Dr. Fone and RecoverIt from Wondershare**

This is app for pc. Download this programs(for premium functions you can install cracked version) and connect your phone to pc. Click on data recovery and you will see "Recovery from bricked phone". It can work when your phone has hard brick or soft brick. After that press on recovery and it will work. If something is not clear for you, you can watch tutorials from YouTube and etc.

These are the ways I know. I hope these methods can help you.

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-boot-loop-android-78426.html

Comment: Wondershare products are scam and won't fix anything on bootloader locked devices

Comment: Sometimes it works. So, I wrote it as option.